# Convergnce of complex sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n+i y_n=x+i y$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=x$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n= y$?

Comment: This is the definition of the convergence in the metric space $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: If the sequence converges then converges to a point of $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^N_{n=m} x_n+iy_n\right| \leq\left|\sum^N_{n=m}x_n\right|+\left| \sum^N_{n=m} y_n\right|
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^N_{n=m}x_n\right| \leq \sqrt{\left|\sum^N_{n=m}x_n\right|^2+\left|\sum^N_{n=m}y_n\right|^2}  = \left|\sum^N_{n=m}x_n+iy_n \right|.
\end{align}

Comment: That is a monster hint.  (+1)